# Parallelize predict in R

Tags: r, hadoop, apache-spark, parallel-processing, predict

I'm working with predictive models in R and I'm
using the mgcv package. The current predictive model runs with GAM. However,
using R is taking many days and I would like to optimize the command.

I'm researching on parallelism with Hadoop and Spark R. I found the predict command on Spark R, but I do not think it has the GAM. Could you tell me if there is any way forward to run the predict we use in R, with parallelism and using GAM?

In other words, can I run the R code below using a cluster with (for example) 4 nodes?

PS: there is the possibility to use Azure, HDInsight

PS2: the code that is taking to many time (actually running just in R server, using just 1 machine)

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)

predict_x <- predict("FORMULA_X", newdata=database_x, 
                     type="response", se=TRUE, cluster=cl)
```

`FORMULA_X` and `database_x` already determined

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parallelise training model with Spark you can't use standard R packages and instead you need to use Spark MLlib. Here is list of supported algorithms: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html#machine-learning

You can also try another R library supporting parallelism: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/index.html

Most complex option is to implement your algorithm in Spark using `RDD` or `DataFrame` operations.

Reason is that you need to have dedicated implementation for training model that enables parallelism.